# Map view Annotation Delegates for swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, mkmapviewdelegate

```
// MARK: - MapView Delegate
override func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationReuseId)

    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationReuseId)
    } else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }
    anView!.image = UIImage(named: "Contactus_gatePin")
    anView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 53)
    anView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    anView!.canShowCallout = false
    return anView
}

override func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    return
}
```

I am getting error for this method in Swift3. It was working in Swift2.2
i couldn't convert this to Swift 3.0
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3 `viewForAnnotation` method of `MKMapViewDelegate` is changed like this.

```
optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

}
```

Fore other methods check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate) on `MKMapViewDelegate`.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

annotation method in swift 3.0

```
 optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    }
```